# Check each element of a string for a number or character

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to make a program that tells the user to type a sentence or something.
Then i need to find how many numbers , characters , all others (symbols, periods, spaces etc...) are in the string.

Why will my code not work? I thing it has to do with the find_first_of checking the whole string at once while i want it to check only the index "i" position.

***[Error] request for member 'find_first_of' in 's1.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[], std::allocator >(((std::basic_string::size_type)i))', which is of non-class type 'char'*** is the error i get in the 2 commented lines of code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string s1;
    int numbers = 0;
    int characters = 0;
    int others = 0;

    cout << "Please type in Something: ";
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << "You typed: " << s1 << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s1) / sizeof(string); ++i)
    {
        if(s1[i].find_first_of("123456789") != string::npos) // Here is where the compiler errors
        {
            ++numbers;
        }
        else if(s1[i].find_first_of("AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz") != string::npos) // And here with the same error
        {
            ++characters;
        }
        else
        {
            ++others;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total numbers in the string are: " << numbers << endl << "Total characters in the string are: " << characters << endl << "Total special characters, symbols, spaces etc... are: "<< others; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::isalpha()` and `std::isdigit()` to check if a character is alphabetic or is a digit.  There is no need to use `find_first_of`

Comment: Thanks my friend i will try it now. BTW could you tell me what is actually wrong however with find_first_of here? Like why doesn't the compiler accept it? EDIT: i cant still use the is alpha or isdigit because i get the same eroor.But if i use it like this s1.find_first_of() or s1.isdigit() instead of s1[i].find_first_of and s1[i].isdigit() then it works but i need to check each specific index. so how do i do that?

Comment: I updated my answer as to why your method didn't compile.

Comment: Yes i tested and it works thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the error, `s1[i]` is a single character, it is not a `std::string`, so attempting to use it as a string object in the call to `find_first_of` will not work (doesn't compile).

---

Your code has at least two other issues:

**Issue 1:**

A `std::string` knows how many characters it has by calling its `size()` method.   Therefore, this is wrong:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s1) / sizeof(string); ++i)
```

It should be:

```
 for(size_t i = 0; i < s1.size(); ++i)
```

**Issue 2:**

Usage of `string::find_first_of` is not necessary.  There are functions that determine if a character is alpha and digit.

```
    #include <cctype>
    //...
    if (std::isdigit(s1[i]))
        ++numbers;
    else 
    if (std::isalpha(s1[i]))
        ++characters;
    else
        ++others;
```

std::isdigit: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

std::isalpha: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems with the code :

1.You can't invoke `find_first_of` on an character :
2.`find_first_of` won't help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string s1;
int numbers = 0;
int characters = 0;
int others = 0;

cout << "Please type in Something: ";
getline(cin, s1);
cout << "You typed: " << s1 << endl;

for(size_t i = 0; i < s1.size(); ++i)
{
    if(isdigit(s1[i])){++numbers;}       
    else if(isalpha(s1[i])){++characters;}
    else{ ++others;}
}

cout << "Total numbers in the string are: " << numbers << endl 
<< "Total characters in the string are: " << characters << endl 
<< "Total special characters, symbols, spaces etc... are: "<< others<<endl; 

return 0;
```

}